# Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed due to a collation conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I try to change the collation of a column in SQL Server I get the following error.

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CS_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in add operator.

Below is the specific query I am trying to run. I get the same error regardless of whether I run the query manually or use the GUI.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myColumn NVARCHAR(152) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI NULL;
```

**Edit:**
Upon doing some more digging I think the issue may occur when sql server tries to rebuild one of the triggers on the table. Partially shown below... I apologize for the awful formatting but I can't seem to get it to format properly

**Edit 2:** Thanks for fixing my formatting! :) The line at the bottom of the code section below seems to be where the error is originating.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[payee_audit_update_trigger] on [dbo].[payee] for update as 
begin
    set nocount on
    declare @userId varchar(50), @sqlStatement varchar(255), @appId int, @transactionId int, @insertChangedValues varchar(255), @auditEnabled char(1), @timezoneOffsetMinutes int
    exec AuditGetSessionInfo @@rowcount, @userId output, @sqlStatement output, @appId output, @transactionId output, @insertChangedValues output, @auditEnabled output, @timezoneOffsetMinutes output
    if (@auditEnabled = 'N')
        return
    declare @auditDate datetime
    set @auditDate = dateadd(MINUTE, @timezoneOffsetMinutes, getutcdate())
    insert into audit_log_tx (company_id, application_id, change_date_time, id, table_name, transaction_id, user_id, sql_statement, primary_key_crc, primary_key_values, changed_values)
        select inserted.company_id,@appId, @auditDate, dbo.AuditGetRowId(newId()), 'payee', @transactionId, @userId, @sqlStatement, binary_checksum(rtrim(inserted.id)), rtrim(inserted.id), 
        case when (inserted.company_id = deleted.company_id) or (inserted.company_id is null and deleted.company_id is null) then '' else 'company_id|' + case when deleted.company_id is null then '<null>' else rtrim(deleted.company_id) end + '|' + case when inserted.company_id is null then '<null>' else rtrim(inserted.company_id) end + '^' end + ...
------
case when (inserted.w4_status = deleted.w4_status) or (inserted.w4_status is null and deleted.w4_status is null) then '' else 'w4_status|' + case when deleted.w4_status is null then '<null>' else rtrim(deleted.w4_status) end + '|' + case when inserted.w4_status is null then '<null>' else rtrim(inserted.w4_status) end + '^' end +
```

Comment: Seems like there is something else you are not showing us. Is this a FK to another table where the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is used perhaps?

Comment: "... I try to change the collation of a column ..." and then there's an `ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...` (with emphasis on `ADD`) statement. How does that match?

Comment: That statement on its own should not cause that error. Does your database or server have any DDL triggers? Is it really the `ALTER TABLE` statement on its own producing that error or something else in the same batch?

Comment: @Igor - It is not a FK. It is a brand new column I'm trying to create.

Comment: I do not see how that statement on it's own would cause that error.

Comment: @stickybit - yes you are correct. I added the column a few days ago before trying to change the collation. When I was getting these errors I tried dropping the column and adding the collation at creation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I am honestly not sure about DDL triggers... It's part of a database that was set up for a software years before I started working here. I will submit a ticket with the software provider. It seems like it's not a simple issue here.

Comment: The better question is why you need to specify a collation and not use the default collation for the database. If you use something other than the default, you (and others) may regret that decision at a later date since many (if not all) other string-based columns use a different collation from the one you are creating.

Comment: @SMor - I am trying to use this column to store id data that is a string of a bunch of different case letters. I ran into an issue where two id's were exactly the same aside from one letter being a different case. SQL server said they were the same when they aren't. Please correct me if I'm wrong but changing to a case sensitive collation would allow me to store these two values in a column with a unique constraint.

Comment: In your last comment you mention about "with a unique constraint" - are there any Unique indexes on this column?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue caused by the fact that I was not connecting with the same collation that I was trying to compare

Comment: @Piotr - I am trying to put a unique index on the column, yes. But I removed it before trying to change the collation.

Answer (score 0):

how about forcing the collation in the query:

if for example is happening at `field1 = field2`

you can force it like:

```
field1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = field1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: How would I implement this in an "Alter Table" statement?